# SELECT rows LIKE tag and LIMIT with offset

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to implement a tag system on the articles on my website. Each article row in my DB has a `tags` column that could hold a string like `php html css jquery`.

When querying the DB I want to return only 10 results at a time. Here's what I'm using at the moment:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM articles WHERE tags LIKE '%" . $tag . "%' LIMIT " . $start . ", 10";
```

It occurred to me that this will not be accurate. When LIMITing the results he will grab the 10 records after row `$start` and then find the ones that contain `$tag`.

What I would need him to do is first find all the rows that contain `$tag` in tags, and *then* limit the results.

It seems pretty straightforward to do this with two queries but is that the most performant way to do this?

**What is the best way to grab 10 rows containing the `$tag` starting at offset `$start`?**

Comment: Um... that's how it works. `LIMIT` applies to the result set, after applying `WHERE`.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol My bad I thought it LIMIT the set first. I would delete question but it has an answer... So my query is good?

Comment: Yes, it's good. The answer you got is codswallop.

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to use a subquery so you are selecting a limit from the already filtered results:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM ( SELECT * FROM articles WHERE tags LIKE '%" . $tag . "%' ) LIMIT " . $start . ", 10";
```

Answer (score 0):

I used to work at a big online news portal provider and we did this type of thing by having a tag and tags tables (with AI ID) which contained item_id and type_id (1 for articles, 2 for images, etc). Then, we get the ID's from that table (which is SUPER fast) and would solve the problem you're having.

```
Like this (tags): (id is only for updates and deletes, and order of addition if needed and not modified by an update)
id | tag | item_id | item_type
1  | 1   | 1       | a
2  | 1   | 2       | a
3  | 1   | 2       | i

Then the tag table:
id | value
1  | php
2  | js
3  | mysql
```

And so on. We then have a clean list of ALL tags for viewing purposes, as well as a really easy way to get the counts of items under each tag. Might be worth a consideration if you wanted to be able to list all your tags in the sidebar, as well as the number of items in each one too.